# Limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}(x^3+x^2)^{1/3}-(x^4-x^3)^{1/4}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(x^3+x^2)^{1/3}-(x^4-x^3)^{1/4}.$$

The solution is 7/12. I dont know who to get to that solution. My thoughts were that the second root is bigger that the first one so the solution should be minus infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $x=1/h$, such that $h \to 0$, if $x \to \infty$

So, the limit becomes $\lim_{h\to0}\frac {{(1+h)^{1/3}} - (1-h)^{1/4}}{h}$

Using L'Hospital rule, we get it to be $\frac{7}{12}$

Answer (score 3):

We have that, for example by using Hopital,
$$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{(1+t)^a-1}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{a(1+t)^{a-1}}{1}=a.$$
Another way: the limit is simply the definition of the derivative of $t\to (1+t)^a$ evaluated at $t=0$.

Then note that if $x>0$ then
$$\begin{align}
(x^3+x^2)^{1/3}-(x^4-x^3)^{1/4}&=
\frac{(1+1/x)^{1/3}-(1-1/x)^{1/4}}{1/x}\\
&=\frac{(1+1/x)^{1/3}-1}{1/x}+\frac{(1-1/x)^{1/4}-1}{-1/x}.
\end{align}$$
Can you take it from here? What is the limit as $x\to +\infty$?

Comment: i dont know how  you solved the  first limit

Comment: Do you know Hopital's rule?

Comment: okay i get it  now

Comment: @RobertZ That hint is arguably circular, in the sense that apply l'Hopital's Rule to the limit requires knowing the derivative of $(1 + t)^a$, but the definition of that derivative (at $t = 0$) is exactly the limit itself.

Comment: (Still, +1 for the nice, efficient solution.)

Comment: thanks for your response

Comment: @Travis Yes, the first limit is simply the definition of the derivative of $t\to (1+t)^a$ evaluated at $t=0$. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Milan Before changing your mind, did you try my hint? Note that the result $7/12$ is simply $1/3+1/4$.

Comment: @RobertZ I changed the accepted answer because the other answer seems simpler and the user has less reputation. I  appreciate your answer very much , and i understood it a year and a half ago when the question was asked